Android switch icons and background colors not displayed in dark theme
I'm making toggle switch with custom thumb and track. The idea is to show ic_sun icon when the switch is checked (with red track) and show ic_moon icon with grey track when the wsitch is unchecked. I did it for light mode and it looks like this:


But when I switch to dark theme it looks like this:


In stead of this there should be the following:

checked: red track with moon in the left and white thumb with red sun on it
unchecked: white thumb with moon icon in the left and black track wuth red sun on it

For the regular switch (withou icons) I use thumbTint and trackTint to change the color for thumb and track. But if I use it with icons the thumbTint and trackTint colors just overlap my icons
app:thumbTint="@color/white_thumb_switch"
app:trackTint="@color/selector_switch_colors_state_list"

Formatted code is here: https://pastebin.com/JmU2pS6D
Could you please help me? I have already tried many options but nothing help.
